# Scheduling Simulation Run in Anylogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am working on workshop model where i have set of service blocks and resource pools associated with it. I want to run the Simulation for 8 hours on daily basis but is should run for a week.
For example the run time is 80 hours, model start on 3 -sept at 8:00AM and run till 3-sept 4:00PM, now model again run on 4th sept 8:00 AM till 4th Sept 4:00PM and process continue till total run time is 80 hours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to consider

1. Simply ignore the date and time completely.
   Set your model tine units to hours and run the model for 80 hours

[image]

[image]

2. Have some object in the model control the work time

Like a little state chart or an event or even a schedule object

[image]

When the workingtime state is entered you simply tell machines to work, when the non_workingtime is entered you stop the machines

Option 1 is the easiest but only useable if you can post-process the actual times or don't need it inside you model

Comment: Actually second method is required as i want to plot the time plot for the period when machines are running. But i need to connect this state chart with my schedule and my process diagram.